# Gulp: minify and unminfy tasks

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify

I am new to gulp so i don't know as much good gulp plugins. I wrote a code for minifying js, css and html using gulp and its plugins which is working fine. But now i am stuck in unminifying code. I don't know which plugins to use which can easily unminify code.

guplfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
    htmlmin = require('gulp-html-minifier')
    csso = require('gulp-csso');

gulp.task('min_js', function () {
    gulp.src('app/**/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('min'))
});

gulp.task('min_html', function () {
    gulp.src('app/**/*.html')
    .pipe(htmlmin({ collapseWhitespace: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('min'))
});

gulp.task('min_css', function () {
    gulp.src('app/**/*.css')
    .pipe(csso())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('min'))
});

gulp.task('minify_all', ['min_js', 'min_html', 'min_css']);

//pending
//gulp.task('unminify',[]);
```

Comment: ?  The unminified versions are still in your 'app' folders.  That isn't good enogh??  They are not modified.

Answer (score 0):

Uglifying/Minifying is attended for production, you should not uglify your code while you are developing (except for testing purpose).
When you start gulp tasks, you have to make sure that you have in one part your "working code", that you will transform into a "destination code".

When you are doing this :

```
gulp.task('min_js', function () {
    gulp.src('app/**/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('min'))
});
```

The code on which you are working on is in the `app` folder, and your transformed code is in the `min` folder (it's the destination folder).
But, if the `min` directory is also used in development, just disable the `uglify` task in development (easier to debug a not-uglifyied file).
There is no need to un-minify your sources, there are still present in `app` folder.